# Ruby: Is there a more efficient way to convert a subset of hash keys to underscored symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to go from this

```
{'productId' => '1234', 'unwantedKey' => 'nope'}
```

to

```
{:product_id => '1234'}
```

assuming in this example I only want the productId key/value.  In the code below, `api_key` returns an array of keys I'd like to extract from the hash.  Is there a better approach?

```
product.delete_if { |k, v| !api_keys.include? k }.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.underscore.to_sym] = v; memo}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [filter the `api_keys`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000765) and then use [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516) to build your hash slice:

```
slice = api_keys.find_all { |k| h.has_key?(k) }.each_with_object({ }) { |k,o| o[k.underscore.to_sym] = h[k] }
```

`each_with_object` is usually a better choice than `inject` if you're iterating rather than reducing.

Given:

```
h        = { 'productId' => '1234', 'unwantedKey' => 'nope' }
api_keys = [ 'productId' ]
```

The above yeilds:

```
slice = { :product_id => '1234' }
```

The `find_all`/`each_with_object` also has the added advantage of being explicitly driven by `api_keys` (i.e. the keys you want) and that may (or may not) matter to you and the people maintaining your code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be doing the each and adding in another hash at the same time:

```
result  = {}
product = {'productId' => '1234', 'unwantedKey' => 'nope'}
product.each do |key,value|
  if api_keys.include?(k)
    result[key.underscore.to_sym] = value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
api_keys = ['productId'] # etc...
product = {'productId' => '1234', 'unwantedKey' => 'nope'}

result = product.inject({}) do |hash, (key, value)|
  hash[key.underscore.to_sym] = value if api_keys.include?(key); hash
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could think about would be whether or not you'd like to avoid the delete pass.

```
final = {}
initial.each do |k, v|
  final[k.underscore.sym] = v if api_keys.include?(k)
end
```

or

```
final = initial.inject({}) do |h, (k,v)|
  h[k.underscore.sym] = v if api_keys.include?(k)
  h
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but since I stumbled upon it, others might too. Here's my take, assuming ActiveSupport core extensions are loaded since you're using `String#underscore`:

```
hash = {'productId' => '1234', 'unwantedKey' => 'nope'}
api_keys = ['productId']

filtered = hash.slice(*api_keys).each.with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[k.underscore.to_sym] = v
end
```